# Correct usage of Repository Factory pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

My repository pattern is setup like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class {}

public abstract class Repository<C, T> : IRepository<T> 
    where C : DbContext, IBaseContext 
    where T : class, IEntity 
{}

public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer> 
{//specific methods here}

public class CustomerRepository : Repository<MyContext, Customer>, ICustomerRepository
```

I added the following method in my UoW class (and interface):

```
public TRepository GetRepository<TEntity, TRepository>() 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity 
    where TRepository : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    object[] args = new object[] { (IDatabaseFactory<MyContext>)databaseFactory };
    return (TRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TRepository), args);
}
```

And in my service I try to get the repository doing the following:

```
var customerRepository = uow.GetRepository<Customer, CustomerRepository>();
```

In Autofac i'm using InstancePerRequest. So the UoW and the repository instances are created per request and disposed afterwards. Do I still need to implement caching of the repositories?

Is this the correct way to use repository factory?

**NOTE**

My UoW and repositories are located in a 'DAL' assembly, my services are in a different 'Service' assembly.

Comment: DbContext already caching query results. I think, you should add caching `IRepository` instances in UoW into `Dictionary<Type, object>`.

Comment: But because the UoW (and the repositories too) live for the duration of the request, I don't think that implementing repository caching in the UoW would be necessary (or makes sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A factory's only job is to construct instances of classes. So in that sense, your factory is correct.

Your IoC container is already managing the life time of the object so there is no need to duplicate that work.

My question is this: Why even have a factory? Your IoC container is already capable of constructing instances. Why not just request an ICustomerRepository from Autofac directly and have it construct for you, instead of requesting a custom object who's only job is to do what Autofac can do out of the box?

Comment: Autofac is referenced only the WebApi project and the container is not passed around various layers (service, repository, etc) so I decided to go with the above solution.

Comment: Ah I see. As with all patterns, remember its about finding a balance between the original definition of the pattern and what you need it for. So if your implementation works for you then it's the right usage!